# Being ARP spoof, how to keep a right ARP cache on OS X?

Tags: osx-lion, home-networking, lan, arp

At dormitory, our PCs/NBs seems to be attack or say arp spoofing? The guy(s) may using the software like "skiller" or "netcut" or much more enhanced software attacking us, we can only use a software called "NetCut Defender" on Windows 7, but how can I defence on OS X?

We cannot connect to the internet while being attack!

Device: MacBook Pro, OS X Mountain Lion (10.8.2), Mid-2012

Comment: If the attacks persist then a technical solution is the wrong answer. Instead have the guy kicked off the network or suspended.

Comment: I have to know what to do while the administrator from school seems not knowing what's going on. And of course, hard to find out who is the guy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Antinetcut](http://code.google.com/p/antinetcut/) is a Python-based solution that explicitly supports MacOS X, and appears to have been written for the precisely your use-case.

Comment: Found it but it's so difficult to use for me, trying and thanks.